Issues with Sending Events to Google Analytics via Measurement Protocol and DebugView
I’m developing an application where it was not possible to implement Firebase for sending events to Google Analytics. As an alternative, I'm using the Measurement Protocol to send data via API, configuring the URL like this:
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurementId}&api_secret=${apiSecret}

However, even with DebugView mode enabled, the events do not appear in DebugView or in the Analytics reports. I would appreciate some guidance on why these API-sent events might not be registering. Additionally, I'm using this setup for the web version, as Firebase Analytics was not supported by the app.
Here is an example of the payload I'm sending:
      LOG  useTracking: Payload preparado para envio: {
  "client_id": "9853e722-e8f6-4b77-98ff-242201f3b3b0",
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "test_event",
      "params": {
        "userId": "479db622-5a68-4124-bda3-fdfba4318b31",
        "user_type": "Responsável",
        "organization_ids": "5fcaa401-e7c2-4390-9a6c-56fc9aab5e09,fa7bbefa-69cc-4654-92b9-3671101a1bdc",
        "professional_category": "Responsável",
        "white_label": "Zelo",
        "platform": "mobile",
        "os": "android",
        "timestamp": "2024-10-25T17:01:06.194Z",
        "dayOfWeek": "Friday",
        "debug_mode": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
 LOG  useTracking: Payload preparado para envio: {
  "client_id": "9853e722-e8f6-4b77-98ff-242201f3b3b0",
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "user_session_started",
      "params": {
        "userId": "479db622-5a68-4124-bda3-fdfba4318b31",
        "user_type": "Responsável",
        "organization_ids": "5fcaa401-e7c2-4390-9a6c-56fc9aab5e09,fa7bbefa-69cc-4654-92b9-3671101a1bdc",
        "professional_category": "Responsável",
        "white_label": "Zelo",
        "platform": "mobile",
        "os": "android",
        "timestamp": "2024-10-25T17:01:06.215Z",
        "dayOfWeek": "Friday"
      }
    }
  ]
}
 LOG  useTracking: Evento enviado com sucesso para o Google Analytics: 204
 LOG  useTracking: Evento enviado com sucesso para o Google Analytics: 204

Specific Questions:
Is this payload correctly structured for the Measurement Protocol?
Are there any configurations that might be preventing the data from showing up in DebugView, either in the API setup or in the app itself?
Any additional steps or recommendations to ensure DebugView captures events sent via Measurement Protocol for the web version?
For more informations, this is my useTracking:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import brandConfig from '../configs/brandConfig';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const measurementId = 'G-XXXXXX';
const apiSecret = 'MY-SECRET';

export const useTracking = () => {
  const getClientId = async () => {
    let clientId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('client_id');
    if (!clientId) {
      clientId = uuidv4();
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('client_id', clientId);
    }
    return clientId;
  };

  const fetchAuthFromStorage = async () => {
    try {
      const storedUserId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
      const storedOrganizationIds = await AsyncStorage.getItem(
        'organizationIds',
      );
      const userType = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userType');

      let orgIds = [];
      if (storedOrganizationIds && storedOrganizationIds !== 'unknown') {
        try {
          orgIds = JSON.parse(storedOrganizationIds);
          if (!Array.isArray(orgIds))
            throw new Error('organizationIds não é um array');
        } catch (jsonError) {
          orgIds = storedOrganizationIds.includes(', ')
            ? storedOrganizationIds.split(', ')
            : storedOrganizationIds.split(',');
        }
      }

    //   console.log('useTracking: Dados de autenticação recuperados:', {
    //     userId: storedUserId,
    //     organizationIds: orgIds,
    //     userType,
    //   });

      return {
        userId: storedUserId || null,
        organizationIds: orgIds,
        userType: userType || 'unknown',
        isDataReady: !!storedUserId,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        'useTracking: Erro ao buscar dados do AsyncStorage:',
        error,
      );
      return {
        userId: null,
        organizationIds: [],
        userType: 'unknown',
        isDataReady: false,
      };
    }
  };

  
  // Função para enviar eventos personalizados
  const customTrackEvent = async (eventName, additionalParams = {}) => {
    const clientId = await getClientId();
    const { userId, organizationIds, userType, isDataReady } =
      await fetchAuthFromStorage();

    const userProperties = {
      user_type: { value: userType || 'unknown' },
      organization_ids: {
        value: Array.isArray(organizationIds)
          ? organizationIds.join(',')
          : organizationIds || 'unknown',
      },
      professional_category: { value: userType || 'unknown' },
      white_label: { value: brandConfig['zelo']?.brandName || 'unknown' },
      platform: { value: 'mobile' },
      os: { value: Platform.OS || 'unknown' },
      timestamp: { value: new Date().toISOString() },
      dayOfWeek: {
        value: new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' }),
      },
    };

    const eventData = {
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      dayOfWeek: new Date().toLocaleString('pt-BR', { weekday: 'long' }),
      action: additionalParams.action || 'AçãoDesconhecida',
      event_category:
        additionalParams.event_category || 'CategoriaDesconhecida',
      event_label: additionalParams.event_label || 'LabelDesconhecida',
      value: additionalParams.value || 0,
      ...additionalParams,
    //   debug_mode: true,
    };

    const payload = {
      client_id: clientId,
      user_id: userId || undefined,
      user_properties: userProperties,
      events: [
        {
          name: eventName,
          params: eventData,
        },
      ],
    };

    console.log(
      'useTracking: Payload preparado para envio:',
      JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2),
    );

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurementId}&api_secret=${apiSecret}`,
        payload,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
      );

      console.log(
        'useTracking: Evento enviado com sucesso para o Google Analytics:',
        response.status,
        response.data,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        'useTracking: Erro ao enviar evento para o Google Analytics:',
        error.response?.status,
        error.response?.data,
      );
    }
  };

  return {
    customTrackEvent,
    fetchAuthFromStorage,
  };
};

I need this help.

What debug view did you check the realtime reports on the google anaytics website?

@LindaLawton-DaImTo I checked both, in Realtime and in Debug View. Neither of them are receiving anything. I'm currently using the emulator, but even when installing the app (APK), no data is received. In the data filter settings, I've disabled any filters.
